# Saving pandas dataframe to file using bcolz

Tags: python, pandas

I want to use bcolz to save a pandas dataframe to file.

I have tried:

```
import bcolz
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(open("mydata.csv", 'rb'), delimiter='\t')
ct = bcolz.ctable.fromdataframe(df)
```

After that, `ct` contains the compressed dataframe, but I can't find how I can save it to file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use bcolz with persistent data containers exactly in the same way than in-memory ones.  You may want to have a look at this tutorial which works with datasets on disk using pandas/HDF5, pure PyTables, SQLite and bcolz:

https://github.com/FrancescAlted/EuroPython2015/blob/master/4-On-Disk-Tables.ipynb

Answer (score 9):

You simply need to specify where to create the table when you read in the dataframe, like so:

```
import bcolz
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(open("mydata.csv", 'rb'), delimiter='\t')
ct = bcolz.ctable.fromdataframe(df, rootdir='dataframe.bcolz')
```

Comment: rootdir is a dir not a file

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `bcolz.ctable` has a `tohdf5` method which you could use; however you will need to install hdf5, pytables, etc. Otherwise you could use `pickle`, which is the usual way to save a generic Python object to disk.

By the way if you're just interested in compressing your data, you might want to look at a more low-tech option like `gzip`; the compression will be just as good if not better than a columnar data format, which is more concerned with doing fast *queries* against your data.

Comment: I have seen an extension of bcolz called bquery that uses the following instruction: ct = bquery.ctable(rootdir='example.bcolz'). So I guess that it is  possible to save a pandas dataframe in bcolz file format. And no, I am not just interested in compressing ; I also want to query.

Comment: hmm looking at the docs it seems that `carray` has a `rootpath` parameter, but `ctable` doesnt ..for some reason... . so you could use a `carray` instead (you'll lose your column names though)

Comment: `ctable` also supports the `rootdir` argument.  See: http://bcolz.blosc.org/tutorial.html#tutorial-on-ctable-objects